# how to use data on jQuery , that data comes from php on html page

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a page , and when the page is started i get data using php like this

```
<?php $data = $this->data;?>
```

and then i want to put that data on the select tags , i mean the select tags will be defined when the page is opened and without any click from the user, i thing this will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Id").val(data);
});
```

but my problems is that the jQuery function is on another file , i mean not on the html file , so how can i send that data i got from php on html to jQuery file

i have html page that used php to get some data

i have js file , i want to use that data on

if i can't explain my problem , tell me to put the code

## some code

## html

```
<?php

    $questionInfo = $this->questionInfo->fetch();
    ?>
    <li>
                <label>Type</label>
                <select  name="type"class="TypeSelector"></select>
                <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </li>
```

## jQuery

```
 $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Type/getAllTypes/TRUE",function(data){
                var options = '';
                options+="<option>Select Type</option>";
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    options += "<option value='"+data[i]+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>";
                }
                if($("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").length){
                    $("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").html(options);
                }
                if($('.TypeSelector').length){
                    $('.TypeSelector').html(options);
                    $('.TypeSelector').val("<?php echo $questionInfo['typeName']; ?>");
                }
            });
```

**on jQuery , check the last line of my code** 
that is what i want to do  , but questionInfo is not identified

I CAN"T USE JS ON MY HTML PAGE , BECAUSE ALL MY WEBSITE HAVE THE SAME HEADER AND SO EVERY PAGE STARTS FROM THE BODY`` , NOT FROM ``

Comment: If the select tags are there from the start, and are in no way dynamic, why use javascript, why not just echo the data on your site with PHP ?

Comment: @adeneo i want that dynamic , because i want to make an edit page , so when the user click it , he should see that values before editing , and then he will edit them

Comment: why downvot , three days trying find the solution , really a problem

Comment: Probably because you were SHOUTING AT THE END.

Comment: @Jivings i spoke politly , i never shout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you edit:

```
<?php
    $questionInfo = $this->questionInfo->fetch();
?>
```

**JS code:**

```
var typeName = '<?php echo $questionInfo["typeName"];?>';
```

and last line of your code:

```
$('.TypeSelector').val(typeName);
```

Comment: finally u came, :) :) , i will try it

Comment: no doesn't work :( , i have edit my question with some code please check it

Comment: after your edit , still doesn't work , but i tried to alert you typeName and i didn't got the value that i want, but i got exactly this `"<?php $questionInfo['typeName'];?>"; 
`

Comment: and when i echo this `"<?php $questionInfo['typeName'];?>";
` on html page i got the right value , that means , that statement works good , but the js doesn't work , right ?

Comment: @Totti I edited my js code with `echo` within php, check that

Comment: i tried it already and doesn't work , the results of alerting your typeName is `"<?php echo $questionInfo['typeName'];?>"; seems that no complile for it , right?
`

Comment: maybe that because `$questionInfo` is on html page , and jQuery function is on anther file ?

Comment: @Totti i edited the js code, it doesn't matter where the js code is, you need to declare the `var typeName` before you js script load

Comment: your edit have a syntax error , do u mean this ? `var typeName = '<?php echo $questionInfo"[typeName]";?>';`
`

Comment: @Totti thank for get the error, it will be `var typeName = '<?php echo $questionInfo["typeName"];?>';`

Comment: still doesn't work, sorry :( , but to be more specific , see this , a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/2gLq2/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11778/discussion-between-thecodeparadox-and-totti)

Comment: Dont you mean <?=$this->data;?> ??

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "<?php $this->data;?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPath/jsFile.js"></script>
```

Now you can use variable `data` on your js file.

Comment: @Ehsam , u didn't got me , i want to get the value of the drop down list , i want to fill it

Comment: thank you for helping but please check my question i can't put a script on my page , because the page starts from <body> not from <html>  , so can i put your script on my <body> ?

Comment: Yes, you can put that on the body.

Answer (score 0):

the best way i know is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Id").val("<?php echo $this->data;?>");
});
```

or

```
var data = "<?php echo $this->data;?>";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Id").val(data);
});
```

Comment: issue is here. <?php echo $this->data;?>
check if this is bringing the data ?

Answer (score 0):

One option (though it is frowned upon, including by me), is to put the jquery script element that needs that value passed in by PHP at the end of your HTML, that way it's loaded in and the script can see the value.  A better way would be to use ajax or refactor your browser-side code in general to have less dependence on php supplied data (at least less dependence as you are seeing it).

Comment: would you put an example pelase , do u mean that i can put a script on the last on my body , ?